# How can I get inital data snapshot from EhCache

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have the following setup:

Realtime_data_source --> EhCache_instance --> web_server --> websocket_clients

Every time a user connects, I register CacheEventListener to the cache. So on new data arrival, updates are handled accordingly. However, if a user connects in the middle of the day, I want him first to receive the initial data snapshot and then updates. Can you suggest how can I configure my CacheEventListener to support the initial data image?

I set up the cache to store thousands of entries by using ResourcePoolsBuilder.

Comment: Can you describe your use case a bit more? What is the content of the cache? For the moment, it looks like you are using the cache more as an event source which may not be ideal.

Comment: My cache contains historical data, say data from yesterday and continuously gets populated with new data tuples. Data itself corresponds to tuples of text and numbers. Since it is continuously populated, every client wants to see this streaming data in addition to historical. Thus I need cache handler that reacts on new tuples added to cache (EhCache has it) and also to be able to fetch all existing records to get full set of historical data. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

From the extended description of the problem, I do not think Ehcache is what you should use.

From the usage of `ResourcePoolsBuilder` I assume you are using version 3.x. As a reminder, a cache is allowed to drop data at any point in time. So while you may see all data arrival, there is no way to guarantee a complete snapshot because the cache could have evicted content.

And aside from iterating over the cache - highly discouraged - there is no support for getting a snapshot of all the data. Even more, with tiers like offheap and disk, the cache could contain a dataset that does not even fit on heap at a given time.

Comment: Thanks @LouisJacomet . Can please point to open source technology that I could use instead of EhCache? I presume Hazelcast is similar to EhCache and also wouldn't be suitable?